# Java string resetting stored value to null

Tags: java, getter-setter, encapsulation

i am new to Java but have 3 years experience in C#, i am encountering an issue where by a String is not retaining its assigned value (using Getter/Setter methods).

my object class is looking like so;

```
    public class filePathPojo {

    private String FilePath;
    
    public void setFilePath(String _Path){
        this.FilePath = _Path;
    }

    public String getFilePath(){
        return this.FilePath;
    }    
}
```

I am having a separate class file with two methods, one is creating a Directory Route with unique value based on who is using application, it is then storing the Path using the Set, the next method is capturing a screenshot and moving to the new directory. Everytime the screenshot method is running and calling the 'Get' it is returning NULL! this is quite frustrating for something so simple.

other class looks like so

```
    public class folderSetup extends filePathPojo {

      public void SetupDirectory(String ScenarioName){

        String Root = "C:\\Users\\" + SomeIdentifier + "\\GherkinEvidence\\SomeProject\\";

        String Today = DateTime.now().toString("dd:MM:yyyy");
        Today = Today.replace(":", "-");
        String dtNOW = DateTime.now().toString("HH:mm:ss");
        dtNOW = dtNOW.replace("/", "-").replace(":", "");

        File file = new File(Root + Today + "\\" + dtNOW + " " + ScenarioName);

        boolean dirCreated = file.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("***Attemping To Create Directory: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        FilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        setFilePath(FilePath);
}

      public String takeScreenshot(String screenshotName, WebDriver driver){
            String path = getFilePath();
            System.out.print("Filepath for screenshot picked up is" + path);
            try {
                WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
                File source = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                //path = "./target/screenshots/" + source.getName();
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path + "\\" + screenshotName + ".png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                //path = "Failed to capture screenshot: " + e.getMessage();
            }
            return path;
    }
    }
```

please done anybody have an ideas?
method calls here;

contained i Step Definitions @Before (FolderSetup)

```
Public Class PerformanceSteps{
@Inject private folderSetup folderSetup;

    @Before
public void FolderSetup(Scenario scenario){
     System.out.print("***Performing Evidence Directory Setup***");
    System.out.println("ScenarioName = " + scenario.getName().toString() + "**");
    folderSetup.SetupDirectory(scenario.getName());
}

}

public class Navigate extends BasePage {

@Inject private com.test.utilities.folderSetup folderSetup;
public void toAppianHomePage(){

    System.out.println("Navigating to Appian URL " + LoadProperties.Appian_URL);
    driver.navigate().to(LoadProperties.Appian_URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    folderSetup.takeScreenshot("Navigate Appian Home", driver);

}
```

Comment: you call getFilePath() but afaik you haven't called setFilePath() on the instance before. Also, I would recommend reading up on naming conventions

Comment: Do you call `SetupDirectory` before `takeScreenshot` on a given `folderSetup` instance?

Comment: Hi yes, SetupDirectory is called from Before Hook, Screenshots are subsequent

Comment: Share the code that calls those two methods.

Comment: @Stultuske - SetFilePath is called on the first method? (the last line)

Comment: @Nightwolf I'm not saying it isn't called, I'm saying it isn't called on the same instance before you call the getFilePath

Comment: i know, they are two separate methods, thats why i am asking the question - the above would be fine in C#

Comment: public class Navigate extends BasePage {

    Inject private com.test.utilities.folderSetup folderSetup;

Comment: public void toHomePage(){

        System.out.println("Navigating to Appian URL " + LoadProperties._URL);
        driver.navigate().to(LoadProperties._URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        folderSetup.takeScreenshot("Navigate  Home", driver);

    }

Comment: @Before
    public void FolderSetup(Scenario scenario){
         System.out.print("***Performing Evidence Directory Setup***");
        System.out.println("ScenarioName = " + scenario.getName().toString() + "**");
        folderSetup.SetupDirectory(scenario.getName());
    }

Comment: @Nightwolf we can't read code in comments, add it as formatted code to the question. Also, the above may (or may not) be fine in C#, but Java isn't C#

Comment: just added the method calls, just reflecting on it i have @Injected Private instance of the class on each page so i think there lies my problem?!?

Comment: keep in mind that if that is your code, it'll never compile, let alone run.
Is this a test class? What @Before annotation are you using?

Comment: Cucumber,Java.API.Before.  its compiling and running the scenarios fine,? its a Maven Project on a custom framework running cucumber tests

Comment: In Java, this doesn't compile: Public Class PerformanceSteps
maybe your config of your test isn't correct. I can't find any example of Inject being used on a variable, instead of on a method, and I can't find any documentation about the annotation

Comment: it most likely is wrong, (the inject part) - the Tests run e2e and all pass (the only exception is with the screenshots) - so not sure about the compile issue.(but i'm not encountering any compile issues - we do use a custom framework). what would be the correct way for me to get/set this data please?